# UIView with multiple masks

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mask

I currently have a UIView with a gradient mask:

```
let maskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
maskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
let innerColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let outerColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
maskLayer.colors = [outerColor, innerColor, innerColor, outerColor]
maskLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.20, 0.80, 1.00]
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
self.myView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

This adds a gradient mask to the top and bottom of the view successfully.

### Question

Is there a way for me to add an additional circle mask (non-gradient) to the center of the view?

Comment: Just use a container view

Comment: "an additional circle mask" Not to _this_ view, no. A given view can have only one mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parent/container layer and add all the mask layer's as it's sublayer.

```swift
let containerMaskLayer = CALayer()

let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 500)
let innerColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
let outerColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
gradientLayer.colors = [outerColor, innerColor, innerColor, outerColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.20, 0.80, 1.00]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1);
containerMaskLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let radius: CGFloat = 100.0
circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.0 * radius, height: 2.0 * radius), cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: 100 - radius, y: 100 - radius)
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
containerMaskLayer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

view.layer.mask = containerMaskLayer
```

Comment: Can that CAShapelayer be just a CALayer?

Comment: Yes, I used `CAShapeLayer` since its easy to create shapes with it.